# Meteor Template onRendered does not work with the same pathFor in iron Router

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

I couldn't know how to handle Template onRendered or similar things as below.

```
<div class="col s1">
    {{#if previous_group}}
        <a href="{{pathFor 'inspection_go' inspection_id=inspection._id group_id=previous_group._id}}" data-transition-out="slideRightOut" data-transition-in="slideRightIn" class="back-button btn-large btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue" ><i class="mdi-image-navigate-before"></i></a>
    {{else}}
        <a href="{{pathFor 'inspection_view' _id=inspection._id}}" data-transition-out="slideRightOut" data-transition-in="slideRightIn" class="back-button btn-large btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue" ><i class="mdi-hardware-keyboard-backspace"></i></a>
    {{/if}}
</div>
<div class="col s4 offset-s6 right">
    {{#if next_group}}
        <a href="{{pathFor 'inspection_go' inspection_id=inspection._id group_id=next_group._id}}" data-transition-out="slideRightOut" data-transition-in="slideRightIn" class="back-button btn-large btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue" ><i class="mdi-image-navigate-next"></i></a>
    {{else}}
        <a href="{{pathFor 'inspection_view' _id=inspection._id}}" data-transition-out="slideRightOut" data-transition-in="slideRightIn" class="toolbar_button btn waves-effect waves-light green" ><i class="mdi-navigation-check left"></i>Complete Inspection</a>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

The above is the code snippet of inspect_go template file.

As you can see, if you have previous or next group, whenever you click previous or next  button, you goes to the same template by pathFor of iron:router, and in this case, the Template onRendered does not invoked because app recognize as we already are in the same page.

```
Template.inspection_go.onRendered(function() {
  // Some things to handle within each inspection_go template
});
```

So I need to find a way to handle some thing when I click inspection_go href to go next inspection_go template.

Please teach me how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

The solution here could be the following: As you do not change the template just add a class to the `<a href>`.
The rest which you could not achieve without the router, do by setting Sessions in js 
click event.

Comment: If I use your method, the page refreshed, and I don't want refresh, so I used data-transition. Is there another way?

Comment: event.preventDefault() in the beginning of the click event and it is not going to refresh. Or use return false in the event.

Comment: I mean the Router.go makes refresh.

Comment: Could you remove Router.go() and work only with the class. I am editing the answer.

Comment: Yes, Router.go makes refresh certainly, so I removed it. But I cannot imagine how to handle things based on Session yet.